# setOnClickListener (unfortunately MyApplication has stopped)

Tags: java, android

Sempre que tento utilizar o setOnClickListener a aplicação para, já tentei vários métodos para tentar corrigir este problema, mas não consegui. o Botão entrar está devidamente setado na R, também no layout, o problema é sempre com o setOnClickListener.

Activity.java:

```
package myapplication.app;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button login;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    if (savedInstanceState == null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.entrar);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setContentView(R.layout.principal);
        }
    });
}
```

Log:

```
02-18 17:39:27.356    1614-1614/myapplication.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: myapplication.app, PID: 1614
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapplication.app/myapplication.app.Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at myapplication.app.Activity.onCreate(Activity.java:30)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: O botão `R.id.entrar` está no xml do Fragmento ou da Activity?

Comment: Está no Fragmento. Encontrei essa mensagem no Exception: "Invalid element:AndroidLightField:entrar"

Comment: Outra coisa @Raphael, já que você está usando fragmentos, sua navegação deveria ser feita usando o Fragmento!

Comment: Posso utilizar apenas apenas o Activity? @IgorCastañedaFerreira

Comment: Claro. Basta remover o bloco que fica dentro do `if (savedInstanceState == null)`. Mas, a navegação por _Fragment_ é um padrão que ajuda a fazer apps que irão funcionar em smatphones e tablets. E a correta forma de navegação entre _Acitivities_ você pode ver nesse [link](http://androidgraffiti75.blogspot.com.br/2012/10/como-navegar-entre-telas-no-android.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ocorre um `NullPointerException` quando você tenta associar um *listener* ao seu botão. Isso, porque o botão não está no *xml* da Activity e sim no *xml* do **Fragment**. Para corrigir, basta que o tratamento do botão seja feito dentro do Fragmento. E não na Activity.

**Activity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    if (savedInstanceState == null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

public void changeView() {
    setContentView(R.layout.principal);
}
```

**Fragment:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    Button login = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.entrar);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((Activity) PlaceholderFragment.this.getActivity()).changeView();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

**Editado**

Conforme apontado pelo @Fernando nos comentários, o método findViewById não pertence ao *Fragment* e sim à *View*.

Comment: `findViewById` não é um método pertencente ao `Fragment` e sim a [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)). Logo o correto no escopo do método do `onCreateView` do `Fragment` seria: `Button login = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.entrar);` ao invés de `Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.entrar);`